# RadioButtonList loses value on button Click

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, radiobuttonlist

I have a `RadioButtonList` in the dataItemTemplate of the ASPX `GridView`. I want the selected index for each `RadioButtonList` on the ButtonClick event. On the button click event the selectedIndex for the radioButton list is -1. How do I make my RadioList remember the user selected values in the button click event.

EnableCallbacks for grid is true

Enableviewstate for grid is true

AutoPostBack for RadioList is false.

```
<DataItemTemplate>
    <dxe:ASPxRadioButtonList ID="m_RadioList" runat="server" 
        Border-BorderStyle="None" ClientInstanceName="RadioList" 
        OnInit="OnRadioListInit">
        <Border BorderStyle="None" />
        <Items>
            <dxe:ListEditItem Text="M" Value="0" />
            <dxe:ListEditItem Text="F" Value="1" />
            <dxe:ListEditItem Text="NA" Value="2" />
        </Items>
    </dxe:ASPxRadioButtonList>
</DataItemTemplate>


protected void OnASPxButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < m_ASPxGridView.VisibleRowCount; row++)
    {
        ASPxRadioButtonList radio = m_AccessPoint_UsersASPxGridView.FindRowCellTemplateControl(row,null, "m_RadioList") as ASPxRadioButtonList;

        int r = (int) radio.SelectedIndex;
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with Muhammad's answer. It's important to understand the ASP.NET page lifecycle. If you databind a control on page load and then click that button it reloads the page, does everything in the page load event before it executes your button_click event. So essentially it is reinitializing the databind. If you don't databind it on post back, the framework will look at viewstate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your grid might bind again in your page load, and that's why your radiobuttonlist also bound again, and you are losing your selected value. Make sure you bind under `if(!Page.IsPostBack)` in your page load.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer I had commented out that line of code.

Comment: That works but the other thing I noticed is that if I apply sort to any of the grid columns. The RadioList selected value is lost. How do I avoid this.

Comment: if you trying to sort, grid automatically rebind and hence you will lost he selection again :(  but if you save that selection and repopulate from DB then you can overcome this.

Comment: How do I save the selection? My RadioList is not data binded.

Comment: As you are getting selected value in click button event, suppose that is your SAVE button and you save those values. Before doing you need to learn some data saving mechnism using Gridview; you can easily search from google a good tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do if you want to bind the `GridView` on page load, is to call a function before the `databind` that reads the `RadioButtonList` in your `GridView` and save it in a static `DataTable`